# Does eventually $\epsilon$-close implies continually $\epsilon$-adherent in Terence Tao's Analysis I?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

I was reading Terence Tao's Analysis where he introduced the (non standard) notion of eventually $\epsilon$-close and continually $\epsilon$-adherent. Where he defined a number $x$ is $\epsilon$-close to a sequence $(a_n)$ if $d(x,a_n)<\epsilon$ for all $n$. And $x$ is eventually $\epsilon$-close to $(a_n)$ if there exists $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $d(x,a_n)<\epsilon.$

He then defined the notion of $\epsilon$-adherent if there exists an $n$ such that $a_n$ is $\epsilon$-close to $x$. And $x$ is continually $\epsilon$-adherent to $(a_n)$ iff it is $\epsilon$-adherent to $(a_n)_{n=N}^{\infty}$ for every $N$.

Is it true that eventually $\epsilon$-close implies continually $\epsilon$-adherent?

Here is my attempted proof: If $x$ is eventually $\epsilon$-close to $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, then there exists $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $d(a_n,x)<\epsilon$. Hence for every $n\geq 1$,$d(a_N,x)<\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $N$ by the assumption of eventual $\epsilon$-closeness.

Is this argument right? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument looks good, but the way it's currently written is a bit confusing. Initially, you let $N$ be a number such that $n \geq N \implies d(a_n,x) < \varepsilon,$ and then you write "for sufficiently large $N$" as if $N$ is now a variable.

Instead, it might be more clear to write something like "Hence, for every $n \geq 1,$ letting $m := \text{max}\{n,N\},$ we see that there exists an $m \geq n$ with $d(a_m, x) < \varepsilon.$"